# Docker + PHP-FPM shows Permission denied when writing files

Tags: docker, docker-compose, file-permissions

Last days i'm stuck with problem that PHP-FPM cannot write nothing when mounting folder data as volume. System is Ubuntu 22.02.
docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    app:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        user: "1000:1000"
        image: dkb-landing
        container_name: landing-app
        restart: unless-stopped
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www:delegated
        networks:
            - landing
    db:
        image: mysql:8.0
        container_name: landing-db
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
            SERVICE_TAGS: dev
            SERVICE_NAME: mysql
        volumes:
            - landing-data:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
            - landing
    nginx:
        image: nginx:1.17-alpine
        container_name: landing-nginx
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - "8000:80"
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
            - ./docker-compose/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
        networks:
            - landing
networks:
    landing:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    landing-data:
        driver: local
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    unzip

RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
WORKDIR /var/www
```

I've set uiser for app container 1000:1000, which is current user UID:GID. Folder and files belongs to this user.
I've tried various manipulations with `RUN chown 1000:1000 /var/www`, `RUN chown www-data:www-data /var/www`, `RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data`. Nothing helped. Main target to make it work, so files of project will be accessible from host and container.
None of guides in internet that i could find (questions on SO too) helped.